# Excel VBA Static (Non-Volatile) Variable - Userform

Tags: excel, static, userform, vba

Hello again Stack Overflow -

Working with a userform in Excel 2010 VBA, I have a textbox called "reviewerName" which should to be given a default value set by the user.  Right now I have the default as:

```
Private Sub userform_initialize()
    reviewerName.text = "Your name here"
End Sub
```

When I open the form, the already has "Your name here" filled out on the textbox.  Great!  But if someone else overwrites it with their name, how do I set the default to the new name?  If I close and open the form, can the reviewerName = "Bob"?  What is the command to update the reviewerName variable so that it is static and can be used next time the workbook is opened?

Thanks!

Comment: reviewName isn't a variable. It's a form field. Perhaps you just want to stick this exact same code into the `userform_activate()` event instead of `userform_initialize()`?

Comment: There isn't a command to persist variables like that.  For forms like this, I'll usually use something like `Application.UserName` or `Environ$("USERNAME")`.

Comment: Is it possible to create a persistent variable by maybe on a command button, writing the new username to cell(1,1) on a sheet and then on the open look at cell(1,1) on a sheet?

Comment: Sure, you can always store data on a worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

Working at it, one way to do it is to have the textbox refer to a value already on the spreadsheet, effectively giving a "static" like variable.

```
Private Sub userform_initialize()
   reviewerName.text = Cell(1,24) 'form will look for a value in column X Row 1.
End Sub
```

Then when there's an action to submit the form, one of the commands should be:

```
Private Sub submit_click()
...
Cells(1,24) = reviewerName.text 'writes a value in column X row 1.
...
End Sub
```

When you open the form again it will draw the value from that cell.